# OpenOfffice Base, inserting the results of a join into a table

Tags: sql, join, insert, openoffice-base

I'm pretty new to OpenOfffice Base, but not to SQL.

I want to insert into a table the results of a join.  It works in the simple case:

```
insert into "tbl1" ("last_name", "first_name") 
select "last_name", "first_name" from "contacts"
```

but NOT with

```
insert into "tbl1" ("last_name", "first_name") 
select "contacts.last_name", "contact2.first_name"
from "contacts" INNER JOIN "contact2" 
    on "contacts.last_name" = "contact2.last_name" 
    and "contacts.first_name" = "contact2.first_name"
```

I get this error:

```
1: Column not found: contacts.last_name in statement 
[insert into "tbl1" ("last_name", "first_name") select 
"contacts.last_name", "contact2.first_name" from "contacts" 
inner join "contact2" on "contacts.last_name" = "contact2.last_name"
and "contacts.first_name" = "contact2.first_name"]
```

But `contacts.last_name` exists and is populated with data.

I've checked docs and don't see it, so I hope someone provide what should be a simple answer.  Also I'd like to know how I can write the results (instead of the insert) to a csv file.  The INTO TEXT clause objects to the join, I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional set of double quotes on every two-part column reference - the table name and column name get quoted individually `"contacts"."last_name"`

Edit: The way I know of to get a CSV file of a query is to import the query results into Calc and then save the Calc file as CSV.  See this guide on importing Base queries (or tables) into Calc: [[Tutorial] Using registered datasources in Calc](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=18511)